# Angular 4 node_modules's folder is heavy

Tags: javascript, angular, node-modules

I've created a new Angular 4 project with the angular-cli...

```
ng new angular-tour-of-heroes
```

...and I wonder why the node folder is so heavy - between 160 and 200 Mo - and how to reduce it?

I understand that a framework needs a lot of vendors and code to work... but I was accustomed to small sized javascript projects, and even if it's a development environment, why should I need non-minified files for vendors that only angular uses (and test folders, and readme...)?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `node_modules` folder size of the application and the size of the built  application (so what you will deploy) is really not the same thing.
First, modules declared in `devDependencies` are not included in and secondly tools as webpack allows to minimize the final build size.
For example my  `node_modules` Angular app does about 200 Mo too but after executing `ng build`, the built application (by default in `dist` folder) does about 12 Mo.